# Enforcing the order of extension loading

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I have two python extensions (dynamic libraries), say a.so and b.so. Of the two, a.so depends on b.so, specifically it uses a type defined in b.so.

In python, I could safely do

```
import b
import a
# work
```

But when I do

```
import a
import b
```

It imports fine, but when running the code, it reports that the type `b.the_type` in a is not the `b.the_type` in b. A close examination with gdb gives me that the PyTypeObject of that type in a.so and b.so have two different addresses (and different refcnt).

My question is how do I enforce the loading order, or make sure that both ways work.

---

In order to make it possible for people who know well about shared libraries but not python to help me, here's some extra information. In python extensions, a python type is essentially a unique global variable that is initialized in its module (the .so file). Types MUST be initialized before it can be used (this is done by a call to python API). These required initialization is wrapped within specific function that has a particular name. Python will call this function when it loads the extension.

My guess is that, as the OS knows that a.so depends on b.so, the system loads b (instead of python) when python requests only a.so. Yet it is python's responsibility to call the module initialization function and python doesn't know a depends on b, so OS only loads b without initializing. On `import b`, when python then actually calls the module initialization function, it results in a different PyTypeObject.

If the solution is platform-dependent, my project is currently running on linux (archlinux).

Comment: Your `a` library should itself use the [C-API to import `b`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html), so as to avoid issues like these.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'd like to keep the two module aware of each other on C level (but as evidenced here must also be aware on Python level). My question is then can I safely call functions b.so directly in C or everything must go through Python layer?

Comment: @YiFei: yet you made these two separate modules.. If they are this dependent on one another they can't be separate Python modules, *or* you need to extract their common base into non-Python (non-global) structures you load separately as a 3rd dynamically loaded library.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You're right.. I guess I could merge them. But instead, can I do a python import from C and then just use it with pure C as if it wasn't python-imported? Would it still ensure the python initialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have *linked* `a` to `b` to import the types `b` defines. Don't do this.

Instead, *import `b` like you would any other Python module*. In other words, the dependency on `b` should be handled entirely by the Python binary, not by your OS's dynamic library loading structures.

Use the [C-API import functions](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html) to import `b`. At that point it should *not matter* how `b` is imported; it's just a bunch of Python objects from that point onwards.

That's not to say that `b` can't produce a C-level API for those objects (NumPy does this too), you just have to make sure that it is Python that loads the extension, not your library. Incidentally, NumPy defines helper functions that do the importing for you, see [the `import_umath()` code generator](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/3b2a7a761d5ceef3b9dcca3fff10380cb7a6f976/numpy/core/code_generators/generate_ufunc_api.py#L36-L74) for an example.